# Beautiful Soup or Python request library does not detect some tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code which tells me that there are no "tbody" tags inside the "table" tag with id='md_7_1' on the web-page which is scraped:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re


url = "https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/all/index.html"

html = requests.request(method='GET', url=url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

matches_index = soup.body.find('div', id=re.compile('matchesindex')).find('div', class_='session').find('table', id='md_7_1')
tbody_tags = matches_index.find_all('tbody')
print(len(tbody_tags))
```

But inspecting the html-source code  of the web-page in the browser shows that there are "tbody" tags (see the snapshot below). Do not really understand why this is happening. How would it be possible to retrieve the information from the within of the "tbody" tag?

[image]

Comment: Why are you a passing a regex for `id=`?

Comment: that part of code works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is loaded asynchronously through Ajax. But you can retrieve the fragments of the website with `requests` (here I just grab the score and name of teams, but you can select more information from the fragments):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/all/index.html'

data_url = 'https://www.uefa.com/{}/season={}/matches/library/fixtures/day={}/session={}/_matchesbydate.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

cupfolder = re.findall(r"var cupfolder.*?'(.*?)'", str(soup))[0]
season = re.findall(r"var season.*?'(.*?)'", str(soup))[0]

for table in soup.select('table[id^="md_"]'):
    _, day, session = table['id'].split('_')
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(data_url.format(cupfolder, season, day, session)).content, 'lxml')
    h, a, score = s.select_one('td.home').text, s.select_one('td.away').text, s.select_one('td.score').text
    match_url = s.select_one('a.sc')
    print('{: <30}{: ^10}{: >30}'.format(h, score, a))
    print('Match url = {}'.format('https://www.uefa.com' + match_url['href']))
    print('-' * 70)
```

Prints:

```
Portugal                         1-0                            France
Match url = https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/round=2000451/match=2017907/index.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Germany                          0-2                            France
Match url = https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/round=2000450/match=2017906/index.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Portugal                         2-0                             Wales
Match url = https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/round=2000450/match=2017905/index.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------
France                           5-2                           Iceland
Match url = https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/round=2000449/match=2017904/index.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Germany                          1-1                             Italy
Match url = https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/round=2000449/match=2017903/index.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Wales                            3-1                           Belgium
Match url = https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/round=2000449/match=2017902/index.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Andrej Kesely, thank for your helpful clarification and the code example. How is it possible to determine the actual url where the data is located (data_url)? I actually wanted to scrap the hrefs inside the tbody tag following which I could get to the web-page with the full time statistics of the match under https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/round=2000451/match=2017907/postmatch/statistics/index.html  ----- here I wanted to get the data from the table "MATCH STATISTICS", but it seems that here the data is also loaded dynamically. How one could find the real url in this case?

Comment: @Riko I updated the code to grab the URL as well. The match url seems that it isn't loading data dynamically, so you can grab it through BeautifulSoup directly. You can replace the last `index.html` with `postmatch/statistics/index.html` to get directly to the table.

Comment: Kasely, indeed you are right that data is not auto generated, thanks. But how were you able to determine (i.e. find)  the data_url (the real location of the data) in the first place? :)

Comment: I tried it in the firefox by going to "Menu -> Web Developer -> Web Console -> Requests" and then loading the web page https://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/season=2016/matches/all/index.html  ---- unfortunately I could not see there  any request with the url similar to data_url, or was it a wrong place in the firefox to look for it?:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the element with this tag is generated using Javascript. To scrape dynamic pages you should use selenium.

Check how to use selenium [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: is it possible to check if that part of the code was generated automatically via java-script?

Comment: Yep. Just disable javascript in your browser and then reload the page. When you do that you can't see the content that are being generated dynamically.

Comment: @Guille, I tried using selenium, but I didn't manage to get it to work. I minimal working code example would be well appreciated (if possible for windows 10)